# Hive RegexSerDe

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to read data from a flat file. It contains a number of lines but want to extract data from the line that looks like:

```
REVISION 12 30364918 Anarchism 2005-12-06T17:44:47Z RJII 141644
```

I only want the 2nd, 3rd and 5th entries on this line and put them into a Hive table; I have issued this command but get an error

```
create external table testTable (
tag string, 
a string, 
r string
) 
row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
"input.regex" = "REVISION\s,[0-9]*,\s,[0-9]*,\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*\s,[0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]*T[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*Z",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s") 
stored as textfile 
location 'hdfs://location:8020/user/bd4-project1/enwiki-20080103-sample';
```

It doesnt seem to work and keeps giving an exception.  Any ideas?
The regex could be wrong, but i just have no idea

I can post the exception later, dont have access to the cluster at the moment

Comment: Usually there is some string escaping involved using double quotes. Have you tried `"REVISION\\s,[0-9],\\s,[0-9],\\s[a-zA-Z0-9]\\s,[0-9]-[0-9]*-[0-9]T[0-9]:[0-9]*:[0-9]*Z"`, or just escape the escapes ?

Comment: \s is what we want to use for space though

Answer (score 3):

I have test this using Hive 0.10.0, it should work for you.

```
create table ts_test2(
  tag string, 
  a string, 
  r string
) 
row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
"input.regex" = "REVISION ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) [a-zA-Z0-9]+ ([0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+T[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[Z]) RJII [0-9]+$",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s");
```

Some notes:
1. make sure your regex is **exactly** correct to macth all the row, or you will get `NULL` in your hive table. **At least** test the regex somewhere like [this](http://rubular.com/)
2. using `()` to wrap the field you are interested in.
3. I am using space, you can change it to `\s` (or maybe `\\s`).