# Load data to hive table from file with different delimiter

Tags: hive, hiveql

I want to load data to hive table created with field delimiter by ','. But my load ready file is '|' delimited. How can I specify the delimiter used in file in Load data syntax.

Comment: is the hive table external?.. can't you change the delimiter in your load read file from pipe to comma using sed or awk?

Comment: That is fine. But it's the Unix approach. I was looking for hive inbuilt method to load this

Comment: can you create first table with delimiter as pipe to match your load ready file and then copy to second table with comma delimiter.. then drop the first table? create table as second_table select * from first table would work

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to mark this as a possible duplicate. But please research well before posting a question here. Please refer to this older thread.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38825285/load-data-into-hive-with-custom-delimiter

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to manage multiple delimiters:

1. [MultiDelimiter SerDe](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/MultiDelimitSerDe)
2. [Regexp SerDe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363890/hive-regexserde)

With MultoDelimSerde you can define your delimiter as

```
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"="[,\\|]"
```